# Scheduled Tasks stopped running

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks, coldfusion-10

Not sure what caused this, but all of a sudden the scheduled tasks have stopped firing on our server, and read as "not run". We are running ColdFusion 10. To test, I created a simple scheduled task, a CFM file that sends an email to me, but it won't run at the scheduled time, and won't run even if I click the manual run button in the ColdFusion Admin. If I just type the page's URL in my browser however, it runs fine and I get the email.

I haven't seen anything indicating a problem in the exception or application logs. We're not running on clustered, nor on SSL. I thought the task might not be running because it was saved with a username/pw (unneeded, but the browser populates those fields by default when creating/editing the task), but I cleared those, resaved the task, and it still won't run.

Comment: Any difference if you try unning it via code, using `<cfschedule action = "run" ...>` and/or `cfhttp`? Also, try publishing the results to a file.

Comment: What do you see in the coldfusion-out.log ?

Comment: It won't run using cfschedule, and I've tried publishing results to file, but it's not writing anything in the file when the task tries to run. And when I click on the run button in CF Admin, it reads that the task was completed successfully. I've read that most of the time this kind of problem is because the url is configured to use Windows Integrated Security, but this one isn't.

Comment: In the coldfusion-out log, it just reads "[Scheduled Task Test] Executing because of user request at Mon Feb 27 13:52:34 EST 2017" (when I click the run button or call it using cfschedule). But it doesn't appear that the code on the page is being executed; it only executes when I put the url in my browser. There's no entry in coldfusion-out for when the task is supposed to be time-triggered.

Comment: Now this is odd - just to test, I put a specific un/pw in the fields for the task, saved it, and opened up the edit task window again, and the un/pw I entered was replaced with a un/pw that has nothing to do with Windows authentication. It keeps replacing the field values with a un/pw that has nothing to do with Windows authentication, no matter what gets entered in those fields (including leaving the fields blank).

Comment: Using cfhttp to call the url is successful; I get the email as expected, but I don't when I use cfschedule, so it would seem something's up with the scheduler. I'll restart CF tonight and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: There used to be a known CF 10 issue with Scheduled Tasks. I've faced myself a several times. Please see if this helps
https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion/coldfusion-10-scheduled-task/td-p/9978004

Answer (score 3):

Looks like something was holding up the Quartz engine; I restarted CF and the test fired off and continued firing off at the interval I set. All settings in the quartz.properties file look good. I'd prefer to know why it was getting held up, but I'll settle for it working now as expected. From what I've read, the Quartz engine seems to be a complicated and touchy piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 4+ years old, but I just had the same issue.  Years of faithful Scheduled Tasks, then we got errors last night to a task not clearing.  Looked and saw the Scheduled Tasks didn't run.  Restarted CF, all is well.